# Microsoft Power BI Crash: "Attempted to read or write protected memory."

Tags: crash, memory-error, microsoft-powerbi

On open, MS Power Power BI crashes immediately with the following error:

```
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Timestamp:
2017-07-17T17:39:15.2141418Z

Local Time:
2017-07-17T13:39:15.2141418-04:00

Product Version:
2.44.4675.521 (PBIDesktop) (x64)

Release:
March 2017

IE Version:
11.483.15063.0

OS Version:
Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.15063.0 (x64 en-US)

CLR Version:
4.6.2. or later [Release Number = 460798]

Workbook Package Info:
None

Peak Working Set:
170 MB

Private Memory:
121 MB

Peak Virtual Memory:
33.2 GB

Error Message:
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Stack Trace:
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.RegQueryValueEx(SafeRegistryHandle hKey, String lpValueName, Int32[] lpReserved, Int32& lpType, Byte[] lpData, Int32& lpcbData)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String category, String counter, Boolean& categoryExists)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String machine, String category, String counter)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean readOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Telemetry.PowerBITelemetryManager.GetProcessorUtility()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Telemetry.PowerBITelemetryManager.GetProcessorInfo()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Main>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)

Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Nullable`1 errorCode, String requestId, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)


Telemetry Enabled:
True

Supported Services:
Power BI
```

I have tried reinstalling the program, making sure the installation is x64; I've tried the **netsh** solution some have suggested; I've tried running as admin and changing the permission settings of the files...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would try updating to the current version (July 2017):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45331